# Redirect to folder IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, redirect

I have a webpage ASP.NET in IIS 6.

There a a lot of urls already indexed by google and links set in web-catalogs that looks like this

www.mypage.com/directory1/page.aspx

Now I changed this that the url looks like this:

www.mypage.com/page.aspx

I want the urls with the directory in the path to redirect to the urls without the directory, so that the links that are set and indexed can stay as they are.

How can I achieve this with IIS 6.

Answer (score 0):

You's use a 301 permanent redirect.

Comment: I know that I should use a 301 redirect but my problem is that I do not know how to configure this with IIS 6 so that all requests that have the directory in it go to the url without the directory. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://iirf.codeplex.com/

IIRF is a ISAPI filter that hooks into IIS and allows you to perform 301 redirects using Regular Expressions.

A Sample IIRF.Ini file to accommodate your situation might look like:

```
RedirectRule /directory1/(.*) /$1 [R=301,NC]
```

This has the effect of removing the /directory1/ from the URL.